# How to fill a circle with a gradient?

Tags: python, matplotlib, gradient, patch, imshow

Is there a way to fill a circle created by :

```
ax.add_patch(ptc.Circle(.....)
```

with a vertical gradient from a colormap :

```
grad = cm.get_cmap('plasma', 100)
```

The expected output:

[image: expected output]

I don't know how to do this, but according to the picture someone got it with imshow ().

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can draw an image and set a clip path:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y, r = 0, 35, 25
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
img = ax.imshow(np.linspace(0, 1, 256).reshape(-1, 1), cmap='plasma',
                extent=[x - r, x + r, y - r, y + r], origin='lower')
circle = plt.Circle((x, y), r, transform=ax.transData)
img.set_clip_path(circle)
ax.use_sticky_edges = False
ax.margins(x=0.05, y=0.05)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]